# Source data and target data mismatching. how can we insert special charcters like 5±3°C and -

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I loaded data in to target table. Data is not coming exactly as source can you suggest

**SOURCE DATA**
ID4581 PEG-INTRON Provide stab data out to end of shelf-life 36 mths at 5±3°C as soon as data becomes avail for PEG Intron Pwdr for Inj vial btchs: 1-IQA-403, 1-IQJ-402 1-IQC-404

TARGET DATA

ID4581 PEG-INTRON Provide stab data out to end of shelf-life 36 mths at 5�3�C as soon as data becomes avail for PEG Intron Pwdr for Inj vial btchs: 1-IQA-403, 1-IQJ-402 1-IQC-404

how can I insert special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your special characters need an encoding. In the current web based system the encoding for the characters you need that seems to be best suited would be UTF-8.

So make sure *everything* is set to use the UTF-8 encoding and it'll work.

So your APIs, database definitions, database data, database connection, scripting, frontend etc: all use systematically UTF-8. If you need something like a 3rd party interface that's not defined in UTF-8, make sure to apply appropriate translations on input and output.

Comment: Yes, Swa, I can able to load exact data. Thank you so much for your help :)